# Is there a TZ independent from countries but with DST in /usr/share/zoneinfo?

Tags: c, linux, timezone

I must set the system time on Linux through data we receive from a database - an integer telling us how far we are from GMT, and a boolean which enables or disables DST.

Setting the time when DST is disabled is easy enough, the files in Etc/ are exactly what we need. Are there similar files that have DST enabled?
I want to avoid setting the system time to the same as specific countries, in case they ever change their policies - we want to make the timezones timeproof.

Besides, some timezones aren't available. There are countries using WET (GMT0) and its summertime WEST(GMT+1) or CET(GMT+1) and its CEST (GMT+2), but for example EAT (GMT+3) does not have a DST equivalent EAST (GMT+4). Maybe it isn't necessary to have this specific zone with DST, but if other timezones can be added independently of countries, adding these as well shouldn't be difficult -- and adding those other, more common timezones is needed. Again, it's to make it as timeproof as possible. Maybe we need custom files? How do we build them? ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73139203/can-we-create-or-change-the-timezone-file-content-in-linux) is related, but it's unanswered)

I am writing this program in C, so if there are any alternatives using C, they are welcome. Remember, I want to change the SYSTEM time, so unless I have misunderstood its use, `tzset()` is out of the question.

Comment: Short answer: there is *not* a good way to do this using the stock tz database.  Given vagaries of time zones and DST, and given the way the tz database is set up, your databse that gives you that integer and offset is, I'm afraid, not a good design.

Comment: I would suggest posting your question to the [tz mailing list](https://mm.icann.org/mailman/listinfo/tz).

Comment: It would be straightforward to set up your own set of tz files.  As @IanAbbott mentions below, you will want the `zic` program.  You will need to create a new source file for it, using the existing "Etc" set as a guide.  You will want to download the "tzcode" and "tzdata" projects and begin learning how to work with them.

Comment: The system itself should use universal time, but the default timezone of the system is set by `/etc/localtime`, which is normally a symbolic link to one of the binary tzfile-format files installed by the tzdata package. You can, however compile your own time zone database sources with the `zic` compiler to create your own tzfile-format files.

Comment: The *gigantic* problem here, though, is: a "boolean which enables or disables DST" is not *nearly* sufficient.  How do you know when DST begins/ends?  That's different for different places, also.  (So I'm now reconsidering my statement that "It would be straightforward to set up your own set of tz files."  Yes, it would be straightforward, but for each of the 24 files desccribing a custom zone based on a UTC offset and a DST=true flag, you'd need to pick a date to turn DST on and a date to turn DST off.)

Comment: @SteveSummit It is assumed that DST starts at the last Sunday of March and ends on the last Sunday of October in all cases. Not ideal, but it's the system that's in place.

Comment: Another possibility, which sidesteps the tz files entirely, might be to use custom settings of the environment variable `TZ`.  For example, if you set `TZ` to the completely arbitrary string `XST5XDT`, you'e asking for a zone 5 hours west of Greenwich that does observe DST.  (I think there's a way to program explicit DST switchover dates, too.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can achieve what you say you want with a set of custom tz files.

The [tz project](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) is a somewhat large and complicated one, and it will likely take you some time to download it, and learn how to build it, and learn how to  use your new, just-built zone files in preference to your system's defaults.  I am not going to go into a lot of detail on all of those logistical details just now.

One of the project's source files is `etcetera`, and it describes the non-geographic, pure-UTC-offset zones like `GMT+5`.  Here is the line from that file that describes that zone:

```
Zone    Etc/GMT+5   -5  -   -05
```

This says that we have a zone named "Etc/GMT+5", with a base offset of -5 hours from UTC, with no DST transition rules, and with an "abbreviation" of "-05".  (Abbreviations are normally things like "EDT" or "CEST", and they're particularly problematic — not necessarily useful — for GMT-offset zones.)

I've just made the following changes to my copy of this file:

(1) I added two "Rule" lines at the end describing your generic "last Sunday of March and last Sunday of October" changeover dates:

```
Rule    DST min max -   Mar lastSun 2:00    1:00    D
Rule    DST min max -   Oct lastSun 2:00    0   S
```

(2) Below that, I started adding some GMT-offset zones *with* DST, like this:

```
Zone    Etc/GMT_DST+4   -4  DST -04
Zone    Etc/GMT_DST+5   -5  DST -05
Zone    Etc/GMT_DST+6   -6  DST -06
```

I haven't picked meaningfully distinctive abbreviations, but the key point is that I *have* specified the new DST-changeover rules (named simply "DST") defined just above.

I then rebuilt the zoneinfo files, placing them in a temporary directory "zoneinfo.exp":

```
make DESTDIR=zoneinfo.exp install
```

I then tested my new zone by saying

```
TZ=`pwd`/zoneinfo.exp/usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/GMT_DST+5 date
```

I got, for me, the correct time, since I live in a zone that's 5 hours west of Greenwich and that does observe DST.  I also tested it on a timestamp from last January, when DST was not in effect, and got the correct answer then also.

Note that none of this actually "changes the system time".  Under Unix and Linux, the system time is always UTC.  That UTC is converted to local time based on a per-process time zone.  The time zone can be "temporarily" set by the environment variable TZ, or the system default is defined by the file `/etc/localtime`, which is typically a symbolic link to one of the individual zoneinfo files, typically stored in a tree under `/usr/share/zoneinfo`.

(Note also that these zoneinfo files define a lot more than just a time zone's offset from UTC!  We typically say things like "I'm in the Eastern time zone, which is 5 hours west of Greenwich, and observes DST", as if that specifies everything.  But the zoneinfo files additionally record, not only when the DST changeover occurs, but also the entire *history* of the changes to the rules for that zone, going back to 1970.  That's why there can be multiple zoneinfo files corresponding to what seems like a single modern zone: the distinct files describe regions with different histories.)

In closing, I have to say that while what I've described here seems to work and seems to meet your requirements, I don't think it's a particularly good idea.  The tuple of (UTC offset, Boolean DST flag) is *not* an adequate way of describing a time zone, because it fails to specify the equally-important details of the DST changeover dates.  But if it's what you're stuck with, this is one way to implement it.